# Using Perl's TokeParser to extract URLs from a tags

Tags: html, perl, parsing, href

I'm trying to parse HTML docs and extract the URLs but cannot figure out how to get the href values for 'a' tags. I'm looking off this documentation if it helps: http://perl.active-venture.com/lib/HTML/TokeParser.html

The issue is within the third 'elsif' code block.

```
sub findTokens {
my $htmlFileName = $_[0];
my $pagesDir = $_[1];
my %titles = %{$_[2]};
my %mapping = %{$_[3]};
my @outLinks;

my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new("$pagesDir$htmlFileName") 
    or die("Can't open $htmlFileName: \n");
my @tokens;
my $url = $mapping{$htmlFileName};

while (my $newChunk = $p->get_token) {

        if ($newChunk->[0] eq 'T') {
            my @lineArray = split(' ', $newChunk->[1]);
            foreach my $i (@lineArray) {
                if ( lc($i) =~ /^[a-z]*\-?\'?s?$/) {
                    push(@tokens, lc($i));
                }
            }
        } elsif ($newChunk->[0] eq 'S') {
            if ($newChunk->[1] eq 'title') {
                $newChunk = $p->get_token;
                    $titles{$url} = $newChunk->[1];
                    #print $url;
                    #print $titles{$url};
            }
        } elsif ($newChunk->[0] eq 'S') {
            if ($newChunk->[1] eq 'a') {

                my %attr = %{$newChunk->[2]};
                push(@outLinks, $attr{'href'});
            }
        }
}

return (\@tokens, \%titles, \@outLinks);
```

}

Comment: Given that you posted "J/K FIXED IT LOL I LOVE AMBIGIOUS DOCUMENTATION" as an answer I am voting to close this as Too Localized now.

Comment: If you are going to have links to Perl modules use http://search.cpan.org/ http://metacpan.org or http://p3rl.org links. ( You can even use http://perldoc.perl.org links if it is comes with Perl. )

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, `HTML::TokeParser` represent the old school.

Since I know `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`, I can't go back to oldish.

Example on your post :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$m->get("http://stackoverflow.com/q/13790575/465183");

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $m->content );

print join "\n", $tree->findvalues( './/a/@href' );
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath

Comment: More like the lazy school (not that lazy is necessarily a bad thing...). TokeParser will get you the answer with less runtime and less memory usage. HTBX will get you the answer with less code.

Comment: @sputnick: HTBX = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath